# foreach in Scala parallel collections

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I have this code evaluated with Ammonite:

```
$ amm
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 2.5.1 (Scala 2.13.8 Java 17.0.1)
@ import $ivy.`org.scala-lang.modules::scala-parallel-collections:1.0.4`
@ import scala.collection.parallel.CollectionConverters._
@ Seq(1,2).foreach { x => Thread sleep x*1000; println(s"Fin $x") };println("Fin") 
Fin 1
Fin 2
Fin
```

It completes ok.
If I add the `par` to parallelize, then it never finishes:

```
@ Seq(1,2).par.foreach { x => Thread sleep x*1000; println(s"Fin $x") };println("Fin")
```

Is this a bug?
With Scala 2.12 I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Parallel collections and REPLs never play well together. You may try just wiring a normal program or looking for the options to tune so it works in REPLs.

Comment: I've tried win an Ammonite script and it behaves the same.

Comment: I'm used to employ successfully parallelism in Ammonite scritps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this problem due this bug with Scala's lambda encoding that will also happen in the Scala REPL.

The bug on the Scala side: https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections/issues/34

The corresponding ammonite bug report is here: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/Ammonite/issues/556

You can work around this in two ways that I'm aware of.
The first is to put your parallel work inside of an object e.g.

```scala
  object work {
    def execute() = Seq(1, 2).foreach { x =>
      Thread.sleep(x * 1000); println(s"Fin $x")
    }; println("Fin")
  }
  work.execute
```

I believe running Ammonite with `amm --class-based` should also do the trick, but I'm not able to test this right now.